# Передача данных из PHP в JSON

Tags: ajax, php, json, javascript

Добрый вечер! Покажите пожалуйста простой пример использования JSON для передачи например двухмерного массива или несложного объекта. Смотрел эту ссылку http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON не понял честно говоря, как осуществляется передача данных. С ajax знаком более менее в простейшем случае это выглядит так (передача разметки html идет тут):

```
$.ajax(
       {type: 'POST', 
        url: 'select.php', 
    success: function(response)
    {
          $('#html-div').html(response);
        }
       } 
      );
```

А как сделать так к примеру, где в файлике select.php идет в php-коде заполнение массива какого-то, который потом передается в index.html файл в котором с использованием JSON должны вывестись данные?

Answer (score 6):

php скрипт вернет Json строку:

```
$street = ['lenina' => '306','mira' => '123'];  
echo json_encode($street, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

jQuery getJSON вернет в data ассоциативный массив:

```
$.getJSON("/getHouse.php", {}, function(data){ 
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        $("#target").text(value);
    });
});
```

Возможны ошибки в коде, очень тороплюсь.

json_encode: https://www.php.net/json_encode
getJson: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: ТС нужно отправить данные через POST

Comment: @Zamony $.getJSON - это укороченная версия $.ajax как $.get, $.post, т.е. вполне можно написать это так


$.post( "getHouse.php", {}, function( data ) {


  $.each(data, function(key, value){


        $("#target").text(value);


  });


}, "json");

Answer (score 0):

Просто заполните свой массив, выполните его [конвертацию в строку](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) и выведите на страницу. Потом в вашей переменной response(в примере) будет строка. Чтобы переконвертировать ее в объект на JS используйте JSON.parse()

Comment: Не понял, в чем отличие этого ответа и ответа выше. На JQuery можно использовать $.ajax с dataType:"json" для отправки POST - запроса. Просто JQuery сам сконвертирует строку в объект.